# Spark partition by key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, partition-by

What is difference between two types of partitions in Spark?

For example: I load a text file toto.csv from disk to spark cluster

```
val text = sc.textFile("toto.csv", 100)
```

=> It split my file into 100 fragments without "rules"

After that, if I do

```
val partion = text.partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(100))
```

=> It "split" my file into 100 partition by key

Thanks to any confirmation or suggestion

Comment: chapter 4 for detailed explanation : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html